# Why does MSVC pick a long long as the type for -2147483648?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, types, integer, literals

My snippet:

```
auto i = -2147483648;
int j = 3;
std::swap(i, j); // Compile error about mismatched types here.
```

The compiler states that the literal `i` is a `long long`. Why is that? -2147483648 fits in an `int` on MSVC x64.

My compiler is MSVC, target is 64 bits.

Comment: related [Casting minimum 32-bit integer (-2147483648) to float gives positive number (2147483648.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11536389/995714), [Why is 0 < -0x80000000?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34182672/995714), [(-2147483648> 0) returns true in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14695118/995714)

Comment: For fun, look up your compiler's definition of `INT_MIN`. Even when `INT` is 32 bits, `INT_MIN` is not defined as `(-2147483648)` for precisely this reason.

Comment: I'm hesitant to close this a duplicate of the last question; opinions welcome.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724320/why-does-the-smallest-int-%E2%88%922147483648-have-type-long

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, -2147483648 is **not** a literal: C++ does not support negative literal values.

It is, in fact, a *compile-time evaluable constant expression* consisting of a unary negation of the *literal* 2147483648.

On MSVC x64, which has 32 bit `int`s and `long`s, 2147483648 is too big for either of those so it fails over to the `long long` type that you observe.

Comment: @P45Imminent, we had the same question in C tag 30 minutes ago, closed as duplicate.

Comment: @P45Imminent, this is the question I am talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724320/printf-d-or-i-minimum-int-value/34724513?noredirect=1#comment57195717_34724513

Comment: I've just upvoted that one. By the way, I'm not at school. I work with Bathsheba. But that one seems to convert to a long.

Comment: That is a platform difference. If the platform has a 32 bit int and a 64 bit long (as 64-bit linux does) then 2147483648 will be interpreted as a long. If the platform has a 32 bit long (as 64 bit windows does) then 2147483648 will be interpreted as a long long (long long is required by the standard to be at least 64 bit).

Comment: The question itself actually contained a big clue that the OP missed, which is the claim that `i` is a literal!