# -9'223'372'036'854'775'808LL is unsigned

Tags: c++, integer, literals, c++20, long-long

Since C++20 two's complement representation is the only representation allowed by the standard, with the guaranteed range from -2<sup>N-1</sup> to +2<sup>N-1</sup>-1. So for a 64-bit signed integer type the range goes from `-9'223'372'036'854'775'808` to `9'223'372'036'854'775'807`. However, this code does not compile on Visual Studio (and neither on gcc)

```
int main()
{
    long long x{-9'223'372'036'854'775'808LL};
    // error C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
    // error C2397: conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to '__int64' requires a narrowing conversion
}
```

Yet, if I replace the code with `long long x{-9'223'372'036'854'775'807LL - 1}` compiles just fine and `x` holds the correct value. What am I not getting here?

Comment: As I understand, it is `long long x{-9'223'372'036'854'775'808LL - 1}` that compiles?

Comment: it is `long long x{-9'223'372'036'854'775'807LL - 1}` which should be the same as `-9'223'372'036'854'775'808LL`

Comment: I thought it was a bug that is not applicable anymore, as it works in recent Visual Studio, but as @user7769147 pointed out it does not work on latest Preview, so seem to be that current behavior is the intention...

Comment: My bad, I overlooked the minus sign.

GCC 9.x shows a [warning message](https://godbolt.org/z/h3sGCE), informing that the value becomes unsigned, but [subtracting 1](https://godbolt.org/z/UaGEAf) (as shown below the example) does indeed compile without trouble. A truly _vexing_ situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without the `LL` suffix the type is taken as the first type in the list in the standard that fits. If you use the `LL` suffix then the value will specifically have type `long long`. However **either way `9'223'372'036'854'775'808` is too large to fit in a `long long`** (which is the largest signed type) so some compilers allow it as an extension to become `unsigned long long`, hence the warning. GCC and Clang [do actually warn in that case](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEAA5SAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxd3JRUw2gYCZmICAONTTkVlTFU/ZNSCCLtHZzdFFLSMoOyFKuLrUujy1wBKRVQDYmQOAHJmAyIAaiMINvEABgBBcQB2WRnh5eHWOmBV9eGAD3npAFoATjA%2ByUkAZhPzuckTyfOANhPXAFZuE7m5l%2BfJ1wsLeYAEXE50W0xWwwA9JDhs5iCRhjpuDwHiBhgZaKkAJ6jawGBTDVAeZzMIjEYbMDweVh4TDoYYjDE%2BYA2ekELHE0jDYiYBQGVgEYb1PCsVjo2jM1lTcEraGw4jw8k6C6HOZotC0ABuzh8dGGVHhRmGJyZeBZdOGAH1LdYCA93n0GahjX1rbb7SduZgAI4GPA8gnMYaYhWoADu1g2Gu1xF1tGlEJ5BG6tB2ILBQOlfQ6rBAfRefVIpj6k0LqDzOjkciFXR6mGGUnOnELBDzpbaHQA1iBJK4AHS/B6STiuTgvVyTB5TyQvIR57iF4ul0jlvqFhQgSakVsl7OkOCwGCIFCoIweEXOciUNBni8uTXIKmWzWcQ6WyTcS3be2kKgigg6pQDhtoWDjWNiebNqQN5GFoBAAPK0KwWIgaQWBGCIwDsKh%2BA8vk2obrupCYNseRDP0UG2soqE0g4xDYnoWCQS2xB4EYzEdDQ9BMGwHA8PwIDnEImEoFWMhCHgDgbpAHREokhGQvBkhQgA6mwrDrrk%2BQaBA5g1KYLyzuYJRRDEIC8CEvh0PpICGZ43hWbQJllC4vDxHkiSFNU%2BiZLZs7udpSQNM5LSuZURQ2XZ9RFCFZncB0Ci1r0XA5nmBZFqhq7ftwowKA%2BwwvocfYfsMEC4IQCKNtkiKnue7Dko25xtIiYnSC2IEdBASA3nVl4UBAPV3igwiiJwkzjb%2B/6ARAwFEWBIYoX0UEwXBiHIThmAYaI2FEbhHl4ARqEkWRAHMeQ9DUURtH0cQWKMRRLFsRxv50IwLDYfxAjZCNYitRJUnwLJHjyXm%2BxKcM%2BxqaKEMqcS6AiGoyAQ/U6AgoCEgyHIkjLgFiSaNoNnZMZTSmeU2SWYkhP2aEfixWTOQJAUDRU7jTMxSTLmCNF3mBFk4VpHTLicAlSV8al%2BaLplebbK4Dz7PawzID9wxjQOA6leVZINhc1V6Le9Xa02zWVpjMjtbunXdbVd5XgN1v1SAwCHEJf4CtNs3LvNEFLYWK30Gti3LuhmE7UH/r7YdRHHcg5FnVRuZXZJN13RgD3bqx7E%2B5xr08R9vACJIwmiKJpvyLR0njCuwN%2BIRYPKZD6kw3DCN4Ej%2Bwo2jGOyDIkjMJpjM6XpPm1MR2iC8EDmU8PfMU7THOhVzWmecz0%2BLwPQXs5EnN1CvvNc8F89mcLnTdMlx8J%2BlS5ltLsvyzlwDIEjRXnBr%2BBa1VXJ671DUXJIxutebdsHQECYGYFgFwlduz2j7K4OYkxuCGXgZMSQcxYFzj6AuUg7EXhbiviuPM65Nzbg6vuI8XUQBdAIB4IYttBoOyEnSCqQsXrcXenxXgYZ6IeGehfSWRFVyNWGBGAgCAdgKyMHlJGhViqYJ3O2fcSBKHUIILQ%2B25RC6MLJIILib1eJcA4VwnhaU%2BHLgEb/IRhBREyzlgrB%2BT8%2BznEAXuchSiaH9TofTTRJBtE5zYfo0gnDKRGIlhlfheYqoWJETsW%2BCslaYRVpMNWy45HZnFpg7BuCpZrkUEQlJHZSDdjmJwPshxODXFHK4ZEztzjnEOOgxxoTTEEOIRbcWkgTHX2yXkjoMY4zmSAA%3D). Contrary to many people's belief, **there's no negative integer literal in C or C++**. `-9'223'372'036'854'775'808` is a unary minus applying to the integer `9'223'372'036'854'775'808`

> ## [The type of the literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)
>
> The type of the integer literal is the first type in which the value can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base and which *integer-suffix* was used.
>
> - no suffix
> - decimal bases:
>
>   - int
>   - long int
>   - long long int (since C++11)
> - binary, octal, or hexadecimal bases:
>
>   - int
>   - unsigned int
>   - long int
>   - unsigned long int
>   - long long int (since C++11)
>   - unsigned long long int (since C++11)
> - ...
> - suffix: ll or LL
> - decimal bases:
>
>   - long long int (since C++11)
> - binary, octal, or hexadecimal bases
>
>   - long long int
>   - unsigned long long int (since C++11)
> - ...
>
> If the value of the integer literal is too big to fit in any of the types allowed by suffix/base combination and the compiler supports extended integer types (such as `__int128`) the literal may be given the extended integer type -- otherwise the program is ill-formed.

In fact there are a lot of similar issues in the past where **`-2147483648` is also unsigned** because at that time `long long` wasn't in the C and C++ standards and the largest type is `unsigned long`:

- [Why do we define INT_MIN as -INT_MAX - 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003893/995714)
- [(-2147483648> 0) returns true in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14695118/995714)
- [Why does the smallest int, −2147483648, have type 'long'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34724320/995714)
- [Why is 0 < -0x80000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34182672/995714)
- [Why does MSVC pick a long long as the type for -2147483648?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34725215/995714)
- [C: Casting minimum 32-bit integer (-2147483648) to float gives positive number (2147483648.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11536389/995714)

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469321/3112916) answers it. In short, unary `-` operator is not part of integer literal.

With `-9'223'372'036'854'775'807LL - 1` you start off landing within the confines of `long long`, set it to negative, then subtract `1`. The other immediatelly starts outside of bounds.

Comment: [Why do we define `INT_MIN` as `-INT_MAX - 1`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003893/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what happens here. First, we have an integer literal of `9'223'372'036'854'775'808LL`. As this is out of range for a signed 64-bit number, it will be an unsigned literal. Now, apply the unary `-` operator. **This won't change the value of this number.**

(Have a look at the same situation, but this time with 8-bit values: 128. If you negate this: -128, it will have the same bit-pattern as -128, in other words, the value doesn't change.)

And as `9'223'372'036'854'775'808` doesn't fit into `long long`, narrowing conversion cannot happen.