# Converting the smallest negative long long value to double changes its sign

Tags: c, floating-point, long-long

I was surprised that converting the smallest negative long long value to double in C changes its sign from negative to positive, so I made a test program.

I'm compiling and running this C program on Linux amd64, linking against glibc:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  printf("sizeof(long long)=%d\n", (int)sizeof(long long));
  printf("% .21g is_negative=%d\n", (double)-0x8000000000000000ll, (double)-0x8000000000000000ll < 0.0l);
  printf("% .21g is_negative=%d\n", (double)(-0x8000000000000000ll), (double)(-0x8000000000000000ll) < 0.0l);
  printf("% .21g is_negative=%d\n", (double)(-0x4000000000000000ll * 2), (double)(-0x4000000000000000ll * 2) < 0.0l);
  printf("% .21g\n", (double)(long long)(-0x8000000000000000ll));
  printf("% .21g\n", (double)(-1ll << 63));  /* But this is undefined behavior: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined [-Wshift-negative-value]. */
  printf("% .21g\n", -(double)0x8000000000000000ll);
  printf("% .21LgL is_negative=%d\n", (long double)-0x8000000000000000ll, (long double)-0x8000000000000000ll < 0.0l);  /* Surprise: positive! */
  printf("% .21LgL is_negative=%d\n", (long double)(-0x8000000000000000ll), (long double)(-0x8000000000000000ll) < 0.0l);
  printf("% .21LgL is_negative=%d\n", (long double)(-0x4000000000000000ll * 2), (long double)(-0x4000000000000000ll * 2) < 0.0l);
  printf("% .21LgL\n", (long double)(long long)(-0x8000000000000000ll));
  printf("% .21LgL\n", (long double)(-1ll << 63));  /* But this is undefined behavior: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined [-Wshift-negative-value]. */
  printf("% .21LgL\n", -(long double)0x8000000000000000ll);
  printf("% lldll\n", -1ll << 63);
  printf("% lldll\n", -0x4000000000000000ll * 2);
  printf("% lldll\n", 0x8000000000000000ll);
  printf("% lldll\n", -0x8000000000000000ll);
  return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
sizeof(long long)=8
 9223372036854775808 is_negative=0
 9223372036854775808 is_negative=0
-9223372036854775808 is_negative=1
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
 9223372036854775808L is_negative=0
 9223372036854775808L is_negative=0
-9223372036854775808L is_negative=1
-9223372036854775808L
-9223372036854775808L
-9223372036854775808L
-9223372036854775808ll
-9223372036854775808ll
-9223372036854775808ll
-9223372036854775808ll
```

The suprising output lines are those not starting with `-`. On the output I'm expecting all numbers to be negative. Especially that:

- For `(double)(-0x8000000000000000ll)` I'm getting a positive output by surprise, even if `(double)(long long)(-0x8000000000000000ll)` gives a negative output (correctly). **What's the difference in here?**
- For `(long double)(-0x8000000000000000ll)` I'm getting a positive output by surprise, even if `(long double)(long long)(-0x8000000000000000ll)` gives a negative output (correctly).

Please note that this is not an issue with glibc *printf* misbehaving on *double* or *long double*, that's proven by by the `is_negative=0` part of the output.

With GCC on Linux amd64, the `double` type is the [64-bit IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) floating point type, with 52 bits for the significand fraction, 11 bits for the exponent and 1 bit for the sign; the `long double` type is the 80-bit [x86 extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) floating point type, with 64 bits for the significand (1 bit integer, 63 bit fraction), 15 bits for the exponent and 1 bit for the sign.

The integer value 0x8000000000000000 can be represented accurately in both `double` and `long double`, because it's a small power of 2. The significand will be 1, the exponent will be 63.

I get the same results with multiple versions of GCC and Clang, both with `-m32` (i386) and `-m64` (amd64).

Comment: duplicates: [`-9'223'372'036'854'775'808LL` is unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61290255/995714), [C: Casting minimum 32-bit integer (-2147483648) to float gives positive number (2147483648.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11536389/995714), [Why is 0 < -0x80000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34182672/995714). Also [(-2147483648> 0) returns true in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14695118/995714)

Comment: Style guide: Don't use lower-case `l` as a suffix; use `L` which can't be mistaken for a digit.

Comment: The greatest-magnitude negative value of type `long long int` is best spelled "`LLONG_MIN`" (requires `limits.h` or one of the other headers that defines it).

Comment: @pts, rather than `printf("% .21g is_negative=%d\n",`, consider a less trouble-some code and print the FP using `%a"` as `.21g` is not certainly the correct precision.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know the answer:

- The type of `0x8000000000000000ll` is `unsigned long long` (!).
- The type of `-0x8000000000000000ll` remains `unsigned long long`, and the value is actually 0x8000000000000000 (positive).
- In `(double)-0x8000000000000000ll`, a positive number gets converted to a `double`.

Sometimes (but not always, even with `-W -Wall`) Clang reports a warning (and GCC reports a similar one): *comparison of integers of different signs: 'long long' and 'unsigned long long' [-Wsign-compare]*

As a proof, the following program prints all 1s:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  printf("%d\n", -0x7fffffffffffffffll < 0);
  printf("%d\n", -0x8000000000000000ll > 0);
  printf("%d\n", (long long)-0x8000000000000000ll < 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(long long)-0x8000000000000000ll` is not that strong a _proof_ as conversion of the `unsigned long long` to `long long` incurs implementation defined behavior as `-0x8000000000000000ll` is likely outside the `long long` range.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: -0x8000000000000000 is likely inside the 64-bit long long range! If long long is represented in 64-bit two's complement form. then the binary representation of -0x8000000000000000 is 0x8000000000000000. What do you mean by outside? (0x8000000000000000 is indeed outside the long long range, it's 1 larger than the largest long long.)

Comment: @pta With 64-bit `long long/unsigned long long` code such as `-0x8000000000000000ll` first creates an `unsigned long long` value of `0x8000000000000000`, then negates it as if `0 - 0x8000000000000000`. Difference wraps around and is again the same `unsigned long long 0x8000000000000000`.   Attempting it to convert via the cast `(long long)` is a problem as that **value** is outside the `long long` range.  C does not specify that the bit-pattern is maintained so the binary representation is irrelevant. The conversion incurs implementation defined behavior.