# Blocking Warnings in c header files

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am writing a header file in c, and i have the problem that there are many warnings, all of them because of big numbers, which need to be unsigned. How can i block all of the warnings that come up in the header file, without blocking the others, from outside of the header?

Thanks

Comment: Try putting a `U` after the big numbers that need to be unsigned. Better yet, post a portion of the header file that's causing problems. See [mcve].

Comment: The U Solution worked but i wonder why, -9223372036854775808 needs an U at the end.

Comment: That particular value is not guaranteed to fit into a 64-bit number because the C standard does not mandate 2's complement representation of integers. On a 2's complement system where `long long` is 64-bits, you can use the `LLONG_MIN` macro found in `<limits.h>` for that value.

Comment: @BjörnMaxJakobsen: Perhaps there is a clue in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34725116/1566221

Comment: Answer in the comments under the original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922335/blocking-warnings-in-c-header-files)