# Why does -32768 have type signed long in the following platform?

Tags: c, types, integer, long-integer, literals

> Suppose that on a platform, the minimal signed
> value is −2^15 = −32768 and the maximum value is 2^15 −1 = 32767. The constant 32768 then doesn’t fit into `signed` and is thus `signed long`. As a consequence, the expression -32768 has type `signed long`. Thus the minimal value of the type `signed` on such a platform cannot be written as a literal constant.
>
> From *[Modern C](https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/modern-c/)* by Jens Gustedt.

It's trivial to understand why 32768 is `signed long`, but why is -32768 also `signed long` and not `signed`, given the minimum `signed` value of -32768?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407498/635608

Comment: If you have 16 bits signed, then 1 in most significant bit means < 0, so max int is 7FFF (01111111 11111111) = 32767 and min value is 8000 (10000000 00000000) = -32768

Comment: *Thus the minimal value of the type signed on such a platform cannot be written as a literal constant* This is not limited to the minimal value, no strictly negative value can be written as a literal constant: `-1` is not a literal constant, it is a constant expression.

Comment: Operators like unary minus `-` may *promote* their arguments to a wider type, but will never *demote* them to a narrower type, even if the result of the operation would fit in the narrower type.  So `32768` is of type `signed long`, and even though the result of `-32768` would fit in `signed`, the compiler won't demote the result to that type.

Answer (score 3):

Because -32768 is the positive literal 32768 (which does not fit into a 16-bit value and therefore must be represented by the next larger type), to which **then** the unary minus is applied (which does not change the type).

If you write e.g. ( ( - 32767 ) - 1 ), you get your constant in int type.

Comment: i don't get the latter i.e. why'll ((-32767)-1) have the type int?

Comment: @dexter: Positive 32768 does not fit into a 16bit int, so the constant is long on a 16bit platform *before* the unary minus turns it negative. 32767 *does* fit into int, gets turned negative by the unary minus, and then you are free to substract one more to get negative 32768 without keaving the range of int.

Comment: @DevSolar [Why do we define `INT_MIN` as `-INT_MAX - `1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003893/995714)

Comment: @phuclv: Yes, pretty much exactly.

Answer (score 2):

If `int` is a 16-bit type in your platform then 32768 doesn't fit in it. Therefore `32768` must have the next larger type which is `long`. `-32768` isn't a negative integer literal but a unary minus applied to the literal `32768`. Since `32768` is `long`, so is `-32768`

This is exactly the same as

- [-9'223'372'036'854'775'808LL is unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61290255/995714)
- [Why does the smallest int, −2147483648, have type 'long'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34724320/995714)
- [Why does MSVC pick a long long as the type for -2147483648?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34725215/995714)

Answer (score 2):

`-32768` is not actually an integer literal.  It's the integer literal `32768` with the unary `-` operator applied to it.

Since on this system the value 32768 is outside the range of `int`, the constant `32768` has type `long`.  Applying the unary `-` to a value of type `long` results in an expression of type `long`, therefore `-32768` has type `long`.

A way to get the value -32768 with type `int`, the proper expression would be `-32767 - 1`.  The integer constant `32767` has type `int`.  Applying the unary `-` operator to it still gives us a value in the range of `int`, then subtracting 1 gives us an expression of type `int` with value -32768.